# Linux Kernel - traverse to buffer heads

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

In the Linux kernel, is there a way to traverse down to the buffer_heads from within a module?

I can see how to get to struct bio (task_struct macro: current->bio). But how can I get to the buffer heads? The buffer_head struct holds some information I'd like to obtain at any point regarding physical block numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I was looking at this wrong.